# Formula to extract the string between the Nth square brackets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Cell A1, A2, A3, etc contain strings similar to the following...

```
1 x Product A [SG014] 1 x Product B [SG026] 1 x Product C [SG023]
```

Each cell in column A could be a string of up to 20 different products and their associated codes (eg SG014, etc).

In column B, i want a formula which returns the first code. In column C i want a formula which returns the second code.... and so on...

Can somebody show me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Text parsing can be pretty convoluted with multiple delimiters (e.g. [ and ]). This may be a case when grossly deforming the text with a large number of spaces then pulling out the desired content and repairing it with `TRIM` might work best.

[image: Grossly deform text]

The formula in B1 is,

```
=TRIM(MID(REPT(" ", 999)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1, "[", REPT(" ", 999)), "]", REPT(" ", 999)), COLUMN(A:A)*1999, 999))
```

Fill right as necessary. Post back if you find the limit of associated codes you can pull before this fouls up; I'd be interested in knowing. If you do find that it is inadequate for a large number of text returns, raise the *999* number to *9999* or higher in all 5 places (999 **AND** 1999). Some quick in-the-head maths tells me that you should be safe for 20 products.

Answer (score 2):

If all the product codes are 5 characters like your example then you could use this formula in B1 copied across

`=IFERROR(MID($A1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE($A1,"[","^",COLUMNS($B1:B1)))+1,5),"")`